# Can't reject an edit

Tags: bug, status-completed

I was reviewing some edits today and went to reject one (which one is irrelevant). After clicking on the reject button I selected the custom option and typed in my reason. I then clicked the reject button on the pop-up window. I was then presented with a red pop-up that stated something like "You appear to be using javascript to avoid clicking a button", or something similarly absurd. The rejection failed. The only JavaScript involved was that supplied by the site itself.

Comment: Was this a one off or is it ongoing ?

Comment: This is a one off for me but I seldom review edits and can't recall if I've rejected one before or not. Accepting edits worked fine.

Comment: My guess is someone wrote a user script that does something that they're wanting to avoid; that's the only thing I can make sense of the message. And something probably went wrong with its validation.

Comment: @Mark, I suspect you're correct on both counts. Of course it's not possible to reliably determine whether a button was click was caused by a human or code and any attempt to do so is doomed to failure.

Comment: It's popping up all over http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144944/trying-to-reject-a-suggested-edit-with-a-custom-reason-throws-incorrect-error-ab

Comment: Ok, it's not just me then. Let's leave it to the devs to sort out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It looks like this problem has been resolved.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144884/cannot-reject-suggested-edits-with-a-custom-reason)

> This is fixed now. Sorry about that.
>
> As part of a refactoring related to the new review UI, we started storing "rejection reason ids" with bytes instead of ints, and I failed to notice that we were representing "custom reason" with -1 on the client side (and bytes can't be negative).

Comment: While that explains why the rejection didn't work it doesn't even begin to explain the error message, so they must have screwed something else up as well.